# Solucionar problema de búsqueda binaria con c#

Tags: c#, árboles-binarios, busqueda-binaria

Llevo unos días parado y no logro saber que me falta en el código de búsqueda binaria.

Hay que dividir en dos el array y buscar hacia abajo o hacia arriba si es manor o mayor que el número encontrado en la mitad del mismo

Tengo algo en el código que sin error deja como un bucle infinito

Alguien podría ayudarme ?

Se trata de generar dos arrays y buscar el número indicado

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int I = 0;
        int CAN = 0;
        int J = 0;
        int ALTO = 0;
        int BAJO = 0;
        int CENTRAL = 0;
        int BUS = 0;
        int AUX = 0;
        string linea;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Console.Write("CUANTOS ELEMENTOS:");
        linea = Console.ReadLine();
        CAN = int.Parse(linea);
        int[] VEC = new int[CAN + 1];
        bool ENCONTRADO = false;

        // INGRESO             
        for (I = 1; I <= CAN; I++)
        {
            VEC[I] = rnd.Next(0, 99);
        }
        // SALIDA DEL ARREGLO ALEATORIO             
        for (I = 1; I <= CAN; I++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(3, I + 2); Console.WriteLine(VEC[I]);
        }             // PRIMERO ORDENAMOS EL ARREGLO             
        for (J = 1; J <= CAN; J++)
        {
            for (I = 1; I <= CAN - 1; I++)
            {
                if ((VEC[I] > VEC[I + 1]))
                {
                    AUX = VEC[I];
                    VEC[I] = VEC[I + 1];
                    VEC[I + 1] = AUX;
                }
            }
        }
        // SALIDA DEL ARREGLO ORDENADO             
        for (I = 1; I <= CAN; I++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(10, I + 2);
            Console.WriteLine(VEC[I]);
        }
        // AHORA SI LA BÚSQUEDA             
        Console.Write("ELEMENTO A BUSCAR:");
        linea = Console.ReadLine();
        BUS = int.Parse(linea);
        BAJO = 1;
        ALTO = CAN;
        // CENTRAL = (BAJO + ALTO) / 2             
        while (((BAJO <= ALTO) & (ENCONTRADO == false)))
        {
            CENTRAL = (BAJO + ALTO) / 2;
            if ((VEC[CENTRAL] == BUS))
            {
                ENCONTRADO = true;
            }
        }
        if ((ENCONTRADO))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Encontrado en la posicion {1}", BUS, CENTRAL);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No existe {0} ", BUS);
        }
        Console.Write("Pulse una Tecla:");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Reviso y reviso y no encuentro nada que pueda causar ese bucle infinito, pero el programa se queda con la pantalla negra y no hace nada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vale, conseguido, me falta un if que limitaba las búsquedas

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int I = 0;
        int CAN = 0;
        int J = 0;
        int ALTO = 0;
        int BAJO = 0;
        int CENTRAL = 0;
        int BUS = 0;
        int AUX = 0;
        string linea;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Console.Write("CUANTOS ELEMENTOS:");
        linea = Console.ReadLine();
        CAN = int.Parse(linea);
        int[] VEC = new int[CAN + 1];
        bool ENCONTRADO = false;

        // INGRESO             
        for (I = 1; I <= CAN; I++)
        {
            VEC[I] = rnd.Next(0, 99);
        }
        // SALIDA DEL ARREGLO ALEATORIO             
        for (I = 1; I <= CAN; I++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(3, I + 2); Console.WriteLine(VEC[I]);
        }             // PRIMERO ORDENAMOS EL ARREGLO             
        for (J = 1; J <= CAN; J++)
        {
            for (I = 1; I <= CAN - 1; I++)
            {
                if ((VEC[I] > VEC[I + 1]))
                {
                    AUX = VEC[I];
                    VEC[I] = VEC[I + 1];
                    VEC[I + 1] = AUX;
                }
            }
        }
        // SALIDA DEL ARREGLO ORDENADO             
        for (I = 1; I <= CAN; I++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(10, I + 2);
            Console.WriteLine(VEC[I]);
        }
        // AHORA SI LA BÚSQUEDA             
        Console.Write("ELEMENTO A BUSCAR:");
        linea = Console.ReadLine();
        BUS = int.Parse(linea);
        BAJO = 1;
        ALTO = CAN;
        // CENTRAL = (BAJO + ALTO) / 2             
        while (((BAJO <= ALTO) & (ENCONTRADO == false)))
        {
            CENTRAL = (BAJO + ALTO) / 2;
            if ((VEC[CENTRAL] == BUS))
            {
                ENCONTRADO = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((VEC[CENTRAL] > BUS))
                {
                    ALTO = CENTRAL - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    BAJO = CENTRAL + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if ((ENCONTRADO))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Encontrado en la posicion {1}", BUS, CENTRAL);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No existe {0} ", BUS);
        }
        Console.Write("Pulse una Tecla:");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Me alegro que lo hayas resuelto por ti, no obstante aquí dejo una solución utilizando las funciones propias de **C#** para realizar una búsqueda binaria.

En **C#** existe la **función BinarySearch** de la **clase Array**. Esta función tiene varias sobrecargas, aquí solamente explico la que recibe dos parámetros: el primer parámetro que es el arreglo como tal y el segundo sería el elemento a encontrar dentro de dicho arreglo.

La función devuelve un entero que sería el índice donde se encontró el elemento buscado dentro del arreglo.

Si el valor devuelto por la función es menor que cero significa que el elemento no existe en el arreglo, si el valor devuelto es mayor que cero entonces el elemento existe y se devuelve el índice de ese elemento en el arreglo.

**Como es una búsqueda binaria el arreglo debe estar ordenado**, por tanto debemos ordenar el arreglo primero.

Para ordenar el arreglo se usa la **función Sort** de la **clase Array** la cual recibe como parámetro el arreglo a ordenar(en este caso que explico, ya que esta función tiene varias sobrecargas con varios parámetros) y no devuelve nada(**void**).

Entonces el código quedaría así:

```
Array.Sort(miArreglo); //De esta forma el arreglo queda ordenado ascendentemente

int resultado = Array.BinarySearch(miArreglo, numero);
//Aquí miArreglo sería un arreglo de enteros y numero pues sería un entero
//Por tanto se busca si el parámetro numero se encuentra dentro de miArreglo

if(resultado < 0)
{
   //Imprimir que no existe el elemento
}
else
{
   //Imprimir que se encontró el elemento
}
```

Para usar esta función debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System;
```